# DropBox file create issue

Tags: ios, dropbox-api, core-api

I am developing a ios app. in that app I am using core api of dropbox. I am able to create a folder on dropbox. But I am stuck on create a file on that folder in dropbox. using core api. Is it possible to create file on dropbox using core api in ios?

Comment: you mean create or upload?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the easiest way to create a file using the Dropbox Core API is with the /files_put endpoint:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#files_put

For larger files, you should use the chunked upload calls:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#chunked-upload
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#commit-chunked-upload